# How to see mails sent through Microsoft Graph API in Outlook Sent mails folder

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, office365, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-mail

Is it possible to see mails sent through Microsoft Graph API in Outlook Sent mails folder? I thought this was automatic, but apparently when I send an email via Microsoft Graph the address that sent the email does not have the sent message inside the Sent folder.

I don't understand if I have to configure my Tenant in order to do this or it's some kind of configuration that I have to write in the code.
I'm using the Microsoft.Graph sdk (4.46.0.0) and sending the email through the `SendMail` method from the `GraphServiceClient`.

This is the message object from Microsoft.Graph, the attachments are a MessageAttachmentsCollectionPage object.

```
var message = new Message
    {
        Subject = "subject",
        Body = new ItemBody
        {
           ContentType = BodyType.Html,
           Content = "bodyhtml"
        },
        Attachments = graphAttachments
    };
```

Then I just populate the Recipient collections (ToRecipients, CcRecipients and BccRecipients)

```
recipients.Add(new Recipient
    {
       EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
       {
           Address = m
       }
 });
```

This is the method I'm using

```
await _graphServiceClient.Users["emailfrom@email.it"]
    .SendMail(message, false)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```

Comment: Can you provide a part of the code for email sending? Have you tried to utilize the parameter `SaveToSentItems`?

Comment: @qwermike I added the code to create the Message object and send the email through the Graph client, the Message class has a lot of properties but none called SaveToSentItems, is it something to write inside the AdditionalData property or something like that? EDIT: Well I answered myself, that false is wrong

Comment: @qwermike yes it's working, thanks a lot for pointing out the name of the parameter!

Answer (score 0):

The error was happening when invoking the client SendMail method, the parameter **SaveToSentItems** must be *true*.

```
await _graphServiceClient.Users["emailfrom@email.it"]
    .SendMail(message, true)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```